# How to trigger css keyframe with Scrollmagic?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scrollmagic

I'm looking for example to trigger CSS keyframe with Scrollmagic but I couldn't find it.
Basically I need JavaScript code to trigger this keyframe with scrollmagic.

```
.project-title-line {
  width: 264px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.4);
  border: 0;
  display: block;
}



@-webkit-keyframes strip-line {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 264px; }
 }
@keyframes strip-line {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 264px; }
}
```